# How to By Pass Request Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a GridView and I need update some data inserting HTML CODE; I would need this data been stored encoded and decoded on request.

I cannot in any way disable globally "Request Validation" and not even at Page Level, so I would need a solution to disable "Request Validation" at Control Level.

At the moment I am using a script which should Html.Encode every value being update, butt seems that "Request Validation" start its job before event RowUpdating, so I get the Error "Page A potentially dangerous Request.Form ... ".

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
        {

            e.NewValues[entry.Key] = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString());

        }
```

PS I USE Wweb Controls not MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method [RegisterOnSubmitStatement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registeronsubmitstatement.aspx) to register script that will encode values of all input-fields before submiting and decode values of those fields at server side.

```
string script = String.Format("var inputs = $get('{0}').getElementsByTagName('input');" + 
  "for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) " + 
    "inputs[i].value = encodeURIComponent(inputs[i].value);", this.ClientID);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "onsubmit", script);
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple textbox or hidden field controls, if the ID of the control begins with __ (two underscores) then the request validation is skipped for those controls.  I used this to have my whole page and site proctected, yet bypass it for one control.  However this is not an offical way so it may be changed in future .net releases.